# Error handling with statusCode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check whether the statusCode is equal to 2xx, however i'm not quite sure how to create this regex code for that type of error handling. Here is my code at the moment with a variable that retrieve the statusCode from header?

```
func SignUpWithPassword(email: String, password: String, delegate: CreateUserDelegate) {

    testProvider.request(.SignIn(email, password), completion: { result in
        switch result {
        case let .Success(response):

            let statusCode = response.statusCode

        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            let description = "Error! Please try again!"
            delegate.CreateUser(didError: description)
        }
    })

    delegate.CreateUser(didSucceed: SignUpUser(email: email, password: password))  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that NSHTTPURLResponse status code is an Int.
 you should be able to use a ranged expression on this in your branching logic:

```
    switch response.statusCode
    {
    case  200 ... 299 :
        print("Success")
    default:
        print("Failure")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this enum:

```
enum HTTPStatusCodeGroup: Int {
    case Info = 100
    case Success = 200
    case Redirect = 300
    case Client = 400
    case Server = 500
    case Unknown = 999

    init(code: Int) {
        switch code {
            case 100...199: self = .Info
            case 200...299: self = .Success
            case 300...399: self = .Redirect
            case 400...499: self = .Client
            case 500...599: self = .Server
            default: self = .Unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift, I have created the own Regax class.

```
    // Custom Regex class
    class Regex {
        let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
        let pattern: String

        init(_ pattern: String) {
            self.pattern = pattern
            do {
                self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
            } catch _ {
                self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression.init();
            }
        }

        func test(input: String) -> Bool {

            let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count)) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>

            return matches.count > 0
        }
    }

    // Override operator

    infix operator =~ {}

    func =~ (input: NSInteger, pattern: String) -> Int {
        return (Regex(pattern).test(String(input))) ? input : -1;
    }

    // Example add it viewDidLoad method   
    let statusCode = 200
    switch statusCode
    {
    case statusCode =~ "2[0-9][0-9]" :
        print("2[0-9][0-9] Success")
        break
    case statusCode =~ "3[0-9][0-9]" :
        print("3[0-9][0-9] Success")
        break
    case statusCode =~ "4[0-9][0-9]" :
        print("4[0-9][0-9] Success")
        break
    case statusCode =~ "5[0-9][0-9]" :
        print("5[0-9][0-9] Success")
        break
    default:
        print("Failure")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, regular expressions are surely a proper and efficient way to compare integer values against ranges!